# UIImage memory change while saved in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, uiimage

I am saving a UIImage to NSMutableArray. After saving, i am talking the object from array and not getting previous memory.

```
[self.arrselectedPhotos addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
```

Currently the size is 191565 (192KB). But when i am taking it from array, the size shows 768786 (750KB+).

```
UIImage *img=[self.arrselectedPhotos lastObject];

NSLog(@"image size: %lu", (unsigned long)[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img , 1.0) length]);
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 days of random R&D, i find out the issue of increasing memory size. I was saving the NSData into array after converting it another image. This is the reason. If i save the NSData directly then everything is ok.

This line is wrong:

```
[self.arrselectedPhotos addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
```

And the correct line is:

```
[self.arrselectedPhotos addObject:imageData];
```

So i can save it furthur easily.

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.arrselectedPhotos];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:self.course_name];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```